# Identify categorical variables when importing dataset in R

Tags: r, class, numerical, categorical-data

I'm importing a large dataset in R and curious if there's a way to quickly go through the columns and identify whether the column has categorical values, numeric, date, etc. When I use `str(df)` or `class(df)`, the columns mostly come back mislabeled.

For example, some columns are labeled as numeric, but there are only 10 unique values in the column (ranging from 1-10), indicating that it should really be a factor. There are other columns that only have 11 unique values representing a rating, from 0-5 in 0.5 increments. Another column has country codes (172 values), which range from 1-230.

Is there a way to quickly identify if a column should be a factor without going through each of the columns to understand the nature of variable? (there are many columns in the dataset)

Thanks!

---

At the moment, I've been using variations of the following code to catch the first two cases:

```
as.numeric(df[,51])                  #convert the column to numeric
len = length(unique(df[,51]))        #find number of unique values
diff = max(df[,51]) - min(df[,51])   #calculate difference between min and max
ord = (len - 1) / diff               # calculate the increment if equally spaced

#subtract the max value from second to max value to find the actual increment (only uses last two values)
step = sort(unique(df[,51]),partial=len)[len] -
sort(unique(df[,51]),partial=len-1)[len-1] 

ord == step                          #check if the last increment equals the implied increment
```

However, this approach assumes that each of the variables are equally spaced (for example, incremented 0.5) and only tests the space between the last two values. This wouldn't catch a column that contains c(1,2,3.5,4.5,5,6) which has 6 unique values, but uneven spacing in the middle (not that this is common in my dataset).

Answer (score 2):

It is not obvious how many distinct values would indicate a factor vs a numeric variable, but you can examine all variables to see what is in your data with

```
table(sapply(df, function(x) { length(unique(x))} ))
```

and if you decide that the boundary between factor and numeric is k you can identify the factors with

```
which(sapply(df, function(x) {length(unique(x)) < k}))
```

Comment: Helpful, but there's no real cutoff in the dataset between numeric/factor, which is why I've been working with a variation of the code posted in the question to try to identify factors another way